# Add class to image in php

Tags: php

I need to insert an additional class in php to the image of this post block:

```
    global $excerpt_length;
                    $bk_length = $excerpt_length;
                    
                    $excerpt_length = 30;
    
                    $this->start_col( 'pbs-col-lg col__md-2_3 mb__xs-2 mb__md-0' );
    
                    $settings['thumb_size'] = empty( $settings['thumb_size'] ) ? 'medium_large' : $settings['thumb_size'];
                    $settings['title_class'] = 'xs__h4 sm__h3 md__h3';
                    Plugin::get_template('template_wide', $settings, $misc );
    
                    $excerpt_length = $bk_length;
    
                    // Begin related by tag
                    if( !empty( $settings['excerpt'] ) && !empty( $misc['ids'] ) ){
                        global $post;
                        $backup_post = $post;
    
                        if( !empty( $post )){
                            $post_id = $post->ID;
                            $tags = wp_get_post_tags( $post_id );
                            if ( $tags ){
    
                                $tag_ids = array();  
                                foreach( $tags as $tag ){
                                    $tag_ids[] = $tag->term_id;
                                }
                                $args = array(  
                                    'tag__in'               => $tag_ids,  
                                    'post__not_in'          => (array) $misc['ids'],  
                                    'posts_per_page'        => 3,
                                    'ignore_sticky_posts'   => true,
                                    'suppress_filters'      => false
                                ); 
    
                                $related_posts = get_posts( $args );
                              
                                if( !empty( $related_posts ) ){
                                    echo '<ul class="pbs-related">';
                                    foreach ( $related_posts as $post ) : 
                                        setup_postdata( $post );
                                        // Plugin::get_template('template_text_list',);
                                        ?>
                                        <li>
                                            <?php the_title( wp_sprintf( '<a href="%s" rel="bookmark">', esc_url( get_permalink() ) ), '</a>' ); ?>
                                        </li>
                                        <?php
                                        if( !empty( $post->ID ) && !in_array( $post->ID, $GLOBALS['wp_post_blocks_listed_posts']) )
                                            $GLOBALS['wp_post_blocks_listed_posts'][] = $post->ID;
                                    endforeach;
                                    echo '</ul>';
                                }
                                wp_reset_postdata();
                            }
                        }
                        $post = $backup_post;
    
                    }
```

If I replace this:
`$settings['thumb_size'] = empty( $settings['thumb_size'] ) ? 'medium_large' : $settings['thumb_size'];`

with this:

`$settings['thumb_size'] = empty( $settings['thumb_size'] ) ? 'medium_large nolazyload' : $settings['thumb_size'];`

This is printed:

`class="attachment-medium_large nolazyload size-medium_large nolazyload wp-post-image"`

And the image is displayed in "full" instead of "medium_large".
I need to add a class in php (no jQuery) like something like this `class="attachment-medium_large size-medium_large wp-post-image nolazyload"`

Thanks guys

Comment: What is printed is what you say you need..? The order of class attributes doesn't matter

Comment: The image is displayed in full, if I enter 'medium_large nolazyload'

Comment: You're passing `$settings` to `Plugin::get_template()`. It's not possible to answer your question without know what that class and method do, or seeing the template. If this is a 3rd party plugin you will have more luck asking its author.